# How to specify payee in paypal api?

Tags: python, react-native, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to create a payment/payment request for a payee on the payers behalf (payer sends money to payee) using the Paypal API. I have no need for a cart/checkout/order that I have seen in other stack overflow posts; i just want to be able to create a payment between a payer and a payee (recipient). I want to be able to do this on my Python backend or React Native frontend.

Ideally I want something like the Paypal 'payouts' API but with a specified payee (their paypal email address/phone number)

Here is the payouts API:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#payouts_post
Here is the payouts data field:

```
{
  "sender_batch_header": {
    "sender_batch_id": "Payouts_2020_100007",
    "email_subject": "You have a payout!",
    "email_message": "You have received a payout! Thanks for using our service!"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
      "amount": {
        "value": "9.87",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
      "sender_item_id": "201403140001",
      "receiver": "receiver@example.com",
      "recipient_wallet": "RECIPIENT_SELECTED"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way I can add a 'payee' field to this request?

Answer (score 0):

"payee sends money to payer" -- that's not what those words mean, rather the opposite (payer sends to payee, always)

Anyway, with Payouts the terminology is sender and recipient. Sender should be the API caller, and sender's account ***must*** be approved by PayPal for Payouts or it will not be able to send Payouts. Such account approval is based on specific business needs, owner must apply for the feature and explain why and what it will be used for.

The receiver can be any email address. If it does not have an existing PayPal account, it has 30 days to claim the funds or they will be returned to the sender.

Comment: Yes sorry, meant to say payer sends money to payee. It seems like I should not be using the Payouts API if the sender needs to be approved. I am mainly looking for creating a paypal/venmo payment request between a specified payee and payer. Would i need to use the Payments API for this rather than Payouts? Sorry, I am a little confused with the terminology the docs uses for 'capturing' a payment.

Comment: You can use the Orders API and specify whatever `payee.email_address` recipient in the purchase_units object.  The payer must sign in to approve each payment. Use the standard checkout approval flow, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/